# как замерить время выполнения функции Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

есть ряд процедур как выявить самую долгую?

сейчас делаю так

```
 long p0 = System.currentTimeMillis(), p1,p2,p3;
 proc1();
 pt1 = System.currentTimeMillis()-p0;
 proc2();
 pt2 = System.currentTimeMillis()-p0-p1;
 proc3();
 pt3 = System.currentTimeMillis()-p0-p1-p2;
```

в Android Studio может есть встроенный функционал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью [TimingLogger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html)

```
 TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger(TAG, "methodA");
 // ... do some work A ...
 timings.addSplit("work A");
 // ... do some work B ...
 timings.addSplit("work B");
 // ... do some work C ...
 timings.addSplit("work C");
 timings.dumpToLog();
```

На выходе

```
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA: begin
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA:      9 ms, work A
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA:      1 ms, work B
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA:      6 ms, work C
 D/TAG     ( 3459): methodA: end, 16 ms
```

Comment: спасибо, но не охота лишний код писать, может есть что-нить в режиме отладки инструмент какой?